# I want to use OxyPlot to implement a custom X-axis tag,just like this.The X-axis shows only the value of the data point.Is this possible in oxyPlot?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

[image]
How can I customize X axis labels like this?

This is my code:

```
private static string _formatter(double d)
{
    if (d == 1000)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}", d);
    }
    else if (d == 2000)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}-{1}", d, "xxx");
    }
    else if (d == 4433)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}-{1}", d, "xxxxx");
    }           
    else
    {
        return String.Format("{0}", d);
    }
}
```

```
this.x.LabelFormatter = _formatter;
```

I use this to set LabelFormatter, but the "d == 4433" is not shown on the plot. The result plot is like this:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Normally we want to help your fix your code, but we will not write it for you.

Comment: I am so sorrry for my Incomplete expression. Now I have added my code. Thanks for that!